# Formula Evaluation Using Apach Poi in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have used Formulas in my excel sheet and using this piece of code to evaluate workbook:

```
  FormulaEvaluator evaluato=wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
  evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues();
  evaluator.evaluateAll();
```

But every time i want to read data from the Excel file I have to use this which is increasing time as it is taking 10 secs to update the values.

So is there any way in which I can use this code in the pre processing of events then sheet is updated with evaluated result. So I don't have to use this code every time I want to fetch values from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

You can evaluate single cells as well, so if you are only interested in the value of some parts of the spreadsheet, it might be sufficient to evaluate only those cells and thus save the time required for all the other cells by "evaluateAll", e.g.

```
switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
        System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
        System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
        break;
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
        System.out.println(cell.getErrorCellValue());
        break;

    // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never occur
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
        break;
}
```

Also see the documentation at https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html for more description and hints.